# Strip quotes from Cookie value

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I am trying to figure out how to remove beginning and end quotes from a cookie value. I create the cookie like this:

```
String value = "qj.w&idjqDJWIj2i0292-/2l2==2-;2;2";

// Cookie belongs to javax.servlet.http.Cookie
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("TestCookie", value);
```

Then I add it to my `HttpServletResponse` object by doing `response.addCookie(cookie)`. When I look at the cookie in my browser (Chrome), the cookie value has quotes around it.

How do I get rid of the quotes? I tried doing

`value = value.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");`

However, that didn't help me, which makes sense as there are no quotes in the original String, so something in the `Cookie` class is adding them.

Please note, I cannot encode it as I want the String to stay as is. Encoding changes some of the characters.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure Chrome didn’t add the quotes for display purposes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. The other cookies I look at that are set do not have quotes around them. And the purpose of the cookie I am trying to set is not working.